# WebDAV "PROPFIND" exception in IIS due to network share?

Tags: iis, webdav

We're finding continuous exceptions in our event viewer on our live box to the following exception:

[snippet]

> Process information:
>
> Process ID: 3916
>
> Process name: w3wp.exe
>
> Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Exception information:
>
> Exception type: HttpException
>
> Exception message: Path 'PROPFIND' is forbidden.
>
> Thread information:
>
> Thread ID: 14
>
> Thread account name: OURDOMAIN\Account
>
> Is impersonating: True

Stack trace:

> at System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context)
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Other Specs: Windows Server 2003 R2 & IIS 6.0

We've narrowed it down to occuring when people try to access shares on the box from within the network, and have discovered (we think) that its due to the WebDAV web services extension being previously disabled by past staff. The exceptions are being thrown when trying to access directories that are virtual dirs in IIS, and plain old UNC network shares

What the implications for enabling the WebDAV extensions on our live web server?

And will this solve our problems with the exceptions in our event log?

Comment: We're only accessing shares via UNC paths (although they are across domains). Why would accessing a plain network share (even though it sits inside inetpub) automatically default to using WebDAV as the folder viewing mechanism?

IE. The address is of the form "//machinename/sharename", which translates to a folder inside our inetpub directory...

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked the same question at serverfault.com: 
[SMB administrative Shares (C$) not accessible on a server running SharePoint - WebDAV MiniRedir reports PROPFIND not implemented](https://serverfault.com/questions/95632/smb-administrative-shares-c-not-accessible-on-a-server-running-sharepoint-we)

Now it struck me that some of the services might be not running. I started the "Server" service using services.msc and UNC works again. So does the Visual Studio Remote Debugger. Hallelujah.

Comment: Unfortunately I've moved onto another company since this question, so we'll never know if it could have solved the issue. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

PROPFIND is in fact a part of WebDav.  Disabling WebDav will prevent users from authoring the website using WebDav extensions.  Enabling WebDav does not pose a security threat, but you do not want to have it enabled if you do not use it.  What it looks like is that someone (or some application) is attempting to update the site using WebDav Extensions. Before enabling it, I would find out where/who is trying to access via WebDav to see if its allowed.  Accessing the share via UNC Path should not invoke WebDav methods and I highly doubt is the cause.

Comment: Thanks Russ. I am aware of WebDav and what it is used for. I am the person trying to access the share and I am not using webdav extensions or any tools like frontpage. I am simply trying to accessing the share via a plain old UNC path from the run menu, and this is definitely the reproducible cause of the exception. We think it is because the machine isn't on our domain, as we are not finding the same problems on other machines on our network. We are putting the machine on the domain tonight, and will report back with our findings tomorrow.